# Update updated_at on related has_and_belongs_to_many models in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have two models with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stories;
end

class Story
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people;
end
```

I'm trying to push an story to a person,

```
Person.stories << Story.first
```

and I'm expecting this will update the updated_at field for the person. However it is not updated. Is there a way to update the field? Shall I use touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2852). The base object is not updated when a new related object is added. If you were using `belongs_to` you could add [`touch: true`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common), but you’re not.

In the discussion of the issue, they recommend adding an `after_save` to the related object. In this case, you’d have to add it to both sides of the relation:

```
class Person
  after_save do
    stories.each(&:touch)
  end
end

class Story
  after_save do
    people.each(&:touch)
  end
end
```

Less than elegant, but should work?

Comment: For information to future readers: "Using callbacks for domain logic is a bad design practice, and can lead to unexpected errors that are hard to debug when callbacks in the chain halt execution. It is our recommendation to only use them for cross-cutting concerns, like queueing up background jobs. " (http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html)

Comment: This appears to do something other than what the OP asks: Touching Child objects when Parents are updated... Rather than touching Parents when Children are added/removed from association.

Answer (score 2):

As [ericpeters0n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655825/ericpeters0n) mentioned in his comment, the accepted answer only shows how to touch Child objects when Parents are updated.

If you want to touch Parent objects when Children are added/removed from the association, you can simply do:

```
class Person
  after_save :touch
end

class Story
  after_save :touch
end
```